# I Want It To Save Pictures By Extension

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-image

All Images Downloaded From Wallpaper Application Are Saved As JPG Extension. I want it to save images by extension. For example, if the image has png extension, I want it to save as png, if it is gif, it should save with gif extension.

```
private static String pictureTempPath = "";
private static final String CHOOSER_MSG = "Choose Option";
private static final String IMAGE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
private static final String IMAGE_EXTENSION = ".jpg";

        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtilities.DateTimeFormat.YYMMDD_HHMMSS.toString(), Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = IMAGE_PREFIX + timeStamp;
        File photoFile = new File(path, imageFileName + IMAGE_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: ???? And ... What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: Saves pictures as jpg due to code in the app. I want it to be saved by file extension instead?
sample:
When downloading file.gif, it changes to file.jpg and saves.
Conversely, when I download file.gif, I want to set it to file.gif
or file.png as png

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand, could you explain a little more?